# Do injective homomorphisms preserve generating sets?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a group with generating set $S$. Suppose we have an injective homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Is it true that $\phi^{-1}(S)$ will be a generating set of the group $G$?

Comment: Not necessarily. It is possible for $S$ to have empty intersection with the image of $\phi$, in which case $\phi^{-1}(S)$ would be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can take inclusion map $\{1,-1\}\longrightarrow \{1,-1,i,-i\}$, considered as subgroups of $\mathbb C^\times$. $S=\{i\}$ is a generating set with empty preimage.